# how to disabling shop cart in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I need a free system witch can handle my product catalog without shopping cart.

I tried to use **( wordpress + woocommerce )** but there is no options in **woocomerce** to disable shopping cart. if it is Impossible in **woocomerce** is there any other solution such as **magento** or **opencart**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this solution:
i install this plugin to wordpress
[ecommerce-Product](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ecommerce-product-catalog/)